# How to extract column names of dataframes from within a list in R

Tags: r

I would like to extract (and change) the column names of dataframes within a list by indexing them (to use in a for loop).

For example this gives me the desired result

```
df_list <- list(df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6))
colnames(df_list$df)
[1] "x" "y"
```

However the following does not:

```
df_list <- list(df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6))
colnames(df_list[1])
NULL
```

How can I do this by referring to the index of the dataframe rather than its name

**Edit: Solved by thelatemail's comment**

Comment: `[[1]]` not `[1]` I'm guessing - probably a duplicate of [The difference between bracket \[ \] and double bracket \[\[ \]\] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use double braket `[[..]]` to access single element in list in R.

The `[..]` method returns objects of class list while the `[[..]]` method returns objects whose class is determined by the type of their values (i.e. a dataframe in our case).